# SDL2 resize buggy in Fedora 21 but fine in windows

Tags: c++, linux, resize, fedora, sdl-2

I'm building a cross platform C++ OpenGL game using SDL2 as the window manager, and I recently discovered that resizing the window has some strange issues in linux. Other windows like Terminal work fine for resizing. It may also be worth noting that Fedora is in a VMware Virtual Machine.

In windows resizing functions as normal.

In Fedora21 resizing acts weird. The best I can explain it is, while resizing the window:

- it always stretches out the right side when the mouse is stationary
- it sometimes resizes vertically to the top of the screen despite only resizing the sides
- Resizing inwards from the bottom works until the mouse is stationary and then the window starts stretching back outwards at a constant rate (while also stretching outwards to the right)
- Only sometimes does the window snap to where you left your mouse when you release it. Other times it stays at the self-stretched position. Depends on which side you're stretching from.
- When the window doesnt snap back to where you released it, sometimes the window moves to the correct width, but located from where the window stretched right to.

I'm aware that it may be something in my code, so I've provided the relevant code below. Let me know if you need to see more. Its just weird that it happens on one OS but not another. I've also compiled on OSX, so I'll see what happens on there as well.

Relevant event cases

```
case SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED:
    if (event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(mainWindow))
    {
        SDL_SetWindowSize(mainWindow, event.window.data1, event.window.data2);
        reshape(event.window.data1, event.window.data2);
        postRedisplay(); // Change state to redraw
    }
    break;
```

And my reshape code

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    g.width = w;
    g.height = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. The problem was that SDL was handling the window resizing, but then I was also manually handling it. I don't know why it wasn't an issue in windows, I guess it is handled differently in windows.

Solution: remove the following line

```
SDL_SetWindowSize(window, event.window.data1, event.window.data2);
```